# .Net service install on windows server 2008

Tags: c#, windows, service, installation

I have the following problem,
I wish to install an application of mine as a service on the system.
My class inherits from System.Configuration.Install.Installer. The problem starts when in the constructor of that class I try to get the parameters of Context property, then I get the following exception:

Unable to create an instance of (my class name that inherits from installer) installer type.

When I printed out the Context property, I saw it was null (and it throws the exception when trying to reach the context property) in the constructor.
Same code works fine on 2003 and installation is finished successfuly, but here it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code from constructor to Install, if possible. A common usage of Installer would be:

```
using ( TransactedInstaller transactedInstaller = new TransactedInstaller() )
{
    transactedInstaller.Installers.Add(myInstaller);
    transactedInstaller.Context = new InstallContext(null, null);
    transactedInstaller.Install(new System.Collections.Hashtable());
}
```

That's why `Context` is null in the constructor.